Customize Inno Setup ReadyLabel1 in script
In the [Messages] section you can customize ReadyLabel1.
However, I would like to include script code to customize the message.
Can I adjust the label text from the InitializeWizard function?

The ReadyLabel1 message is shown on WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.
That label is updated when you enter the page. So if you want to update it programmatically, you need to do it only once your enter the "Ready" page. So from CurPageChanged(wpReady) event:
[Code]

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpReady then
  begin
    WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Caption :=
      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ' +
      'sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';
  end; 
end;



Fantastic, thank you!
